# java script - properties file gibberish with Hebrew values

Tags: javascript, properties

I have text.properties  file which his content is :

```
 { "loginText": "התחבר", "b": false }
```

I get the text in this way (it's angular but not matter):

```
   $http.get('text.properties').then(function (response) {
```

console.log("response.data",response.data.loginText); //print "?????" to console
            $rootScope.text = response.data.loginText; //also on screen it's appear as "?????"
          });

now $rootScope.text.login is "?????"

edit:

also this cause '?????':

```
  $http.get('text.properties',
  {"headers" : "Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})

              .success(function(data, status, header, config){

   console.log("data",data);

              });
```

Comment: Looks like the encoding of your JS file (or JSON?) is broken?

Comment: Use the proper HTTP headers for serving the file.

Comment: if i chage the content of the file to { "loginText": "login", "b": false } it's work fine. the problem is the hebrew

Comment: Sure. Because only the characters outside of the ASCII range are stored/sent in a different format than the server tells it would send them in.

Comment: The request headers are irrelevant. What *response headers* does the server send?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your charset in a meta tag on the page to render UTF-8 characters:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```